# what means by top of the page in php file

Tags: php, html

- i read somewhere that `ob_start()` should be places top of the page. whereas
- somewhere i read that `session_start()` should be placed on the top of the page.
- somewhere i read `header()` should be placed on the top of the page.
- somewhere i read  `include()` or `require()` should be placed on the top of the page.

i m getting confused what should be written on the top and in which order ther are placed ? and what means by **on the top???** is it

- before `<html>` or
- after `<html>` or before `<head>` or
- after `<head>`

please tell me what is real order of all these function

like same manner where we have to put ob_end_flush(); and other function,  at the bottom of the page  after `<html>` or after `</body>` and what is the order of functions that comes on the bottom of the page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to understand the value of the statements you have written you need to have some basic understanding of the operations of the functions you mention. I'll try to break them down here.

Let's start with `session_start()` and `header()` calls:
The first function does exactly what the name implies; it starts a session.

Due to the stateless nature of the HTTP protocol, there is a need for some mechanism that can remember state between page requests. This can be achieved with sessions. Although sessions, in the early days of PHP where sometimes propagated by passing along the session ID in links ( `someurl?sessionId=someSessionHash` ), this, nowadays, is considered bad practice.

Nowadays, sessions are predominantly kept track of by using a cookie (in the early days they where widely used too, don't get me wrong). This session cookie (which, contrary to popular belief, is nothing more than a normal cookie, with merely the session ID in it, that (usualy) simply expires after you close your browser) is sent along to the browser with each subsequent page request. And here is where the catch is: A cookie is sent as a header of the response (meaning before the actual body), like so:

```
// I've left out a lot of other headers for brevity
HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Date: Sun, 31 Jan 2010 09:37:35 GMT
Cookie: SESSION=DRwHHwAAACpes38Ql6LlhGr2t70df // here is your Cookie header

// after all response headers come the actual content: 
// the response body, for instance:
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, because response headers must be sent before the response body, you need to put a call to `session_start()` and `header()` before any body content is output. Here's why: if you output any response body content (could be something as simple as a whitespace character) before a call to `session_start()` or `header()`, PHP will automatically output the response headers. This is because a HTTP response must have the response headers sent out first before the response body. And it is exactly this that often leads to the infamous `Warning: headers already sent` warning in PHP. In other words; once PHP has sent out the headers, because it had to send body data too, it cannot add any headers anymore.

So, now that you understand this about the HTTP protocol, there are some measurements you can take to prevent this from happening. And this is where we come to the next function(s):

`ob_start`, `ob_flush`, etc...:
In a default setup PHP usualy outputs anything immediately. Therefor, if you output any response body content, headers are automatically sent first.
But PHP offers mechanisms of buffering output. This is the `ob_*` family of functions. With `ob_start` you tell PHP to start buffering. And with `ob_flush` you tell PHP to flush the buffer; in other words output the current content of the buffer to the standard output.

With these buffering mechanisms you can still add headers to the response, after you have output body data, because you haven't actually sent body data yet, you have simply buffered it, to be output later with a call to `ob_flush` or `ob_end_flush` and what have you.

Keep in mind though, that using `ob_*` functions is more than often a code smell. In other words (and this is why it is important to do certain stuff at the top), it is then used to make up for poor design. Somebody forgot to set up their order of operations properly and resorts to output buffering to circumvent this `header` and `session` drama.

Having said all this, you can easily see why the outputting of html and/or other body content should come last. Apart from that, I strongly recommend you to separate PHP code from output code anyway. Because it is much more easy to read and understand. And a good way to start doing that is having the actual html come after the main `<?php ?>` code block. But there are other ways as well, which is beyond this questions scope.

Then lastly about the `include` and `require` calls. To have these at the top of your php files is usually ment to be clarifying. It keeps these calls nicely in one place. But keep in mind, that if one of these files output anything before you call `session_start()` or `header()` without using output buffering, you're screwed again.

Comment: Thank You very Much Fireeyedboy, but i still don't know what would be the order( don't take me wrong)...please suggest me 
which is better sequence `ob_start(); session_start();,header();`
 or `session_start();ob_start();header();`

Comment: Well, if you are going to resort to `ob_start` you must call it before `session_start` and `header` and before any other output.

Comment: what means by resort to `ob_start()`??

Comment: But read my answer again, carefully, until you fully understand it. Then you could have come to this same conclusion.

Comment: What I mean by that is, that you don't want to use it in most cases. But if you **have** to, then this is the way to go. 'Resort' means something like 'to fall back on', 'as a last measurement`, etc...

Answer (score 4):

"Top of the page" means before any output. "Bottom of the page" means after all output.

Comment: this is not the answer dear? please write me the order
and i know what means by top of the page,
 i asked where i have to put them

Comment: You put it before you send any output to the client. Period. End of story. The exact location *does not matter*.

Comment: That order is acceptable, provided that there is no whitespace before the initial PHP open angle bracket.

Answer (score 2):

It simply means before any other character, where "other" means "non PHP code".

All code between `<?php` and `?>` is not sent to the browser, so it doesn't count. Thus usually "top of the page" means before the `<html>` start tag. Be careful because if you have an empty line or even just one single whitespace before that tag (or even before the PHP opening tag), that counts as output.

Comment: if i write `ob_start();` and then hit enter and then one tab( for indentation) and write `session_start();` then is it counted as output??

Comment: i have heard that if we use `header()` in the page then , there should be no echo before header, and no function, keyword or file name which contain the word `header`