# Don't allow to resend POST information after reload

Tags: php

I have a form that once its submitted the result should not be replicated again by reloading the page, I've tried to assign a random key so that when you reload the page the keys won't match and you won't be able to replicate it but it doesn't work:

```
$bypass = rand(1,999);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    if ($_POST['key'] == $bypass) {
        echo'Hello';
    } else {
        echo "invalid key";
    }
} else {
    echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="key" value="'.$bypass.'" /><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></form>';
}
```

The intended function for the code above is to generate a random key that will only work when you submit the form but will now work if you resend the form by reloading the page but it doesn't work as when you submit the form the key will be changed. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you dont want the form data reloaded, destroy whereever you are storing it for when you do want it reloaded.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666882/how-to-avoid-resending-data-on-refresh-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is to redirect away from the POST endpoint, so that the browser does a GET which can be refreshed as much as it wants without resending the POST data.

If you do want to do it all on the POST endpoint, something like this should do it:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['bypass']) {
    $_SESSION['bypass'] = mt_rand();
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if ($_POST['key'] != $_SESSION['bypass']) {
        echo "Invalid key";
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION['bypass']);
        echo "Hello";
    }
} else {
    echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="key" value="'.$_SESSION['bypass'].'" /><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></form>';
}
```

Comment: +1 I generally use the "redirect" method and pass any errors or values I need back to the page via the URL's query string.