# How to avoid uploading of videos dynamically upon "refreshing" the page in browser?

Tags: php, forms, video

Here I can upload videos successfully into database and videos are saving in appropriate folder named "uploaded". As I mentioned in question, once after uploading the video, if I refresh the browser the previously uploaded video is going saving in my database. Another question is, if I click on the video(displayed name in myvideo.php), video is not going to display instead I am getting "Object Not Found" error. I request you people to give me solutions to solve these problems. Below I am posting my code:

**myvideo.php:**

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="header" id="stand-fix" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1;">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        // $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "videos") or die(mysqli_error());
        $name = (isset($_FILES['file']['name']) ? $_FILES['file']['name'] : '');
        $temp = (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] : '');
        move_uploaded_file($temp, "uploaded/".$name);
        $url = "http://192.168.0.20/PHP/video%20upload%20and%20playback/uploaded/$name";
        mysqli_query($database, "INSERT INTO video VALUE ('','$name','$url')");
    }
?>
            <form action="myvideo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <h4 class="title">My Videos</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="file" name="file" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 15px;"><br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="font-size: 15px;" value="Upload">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    echo '<script language="javascript">';
                    echo 'alert("Your video has been successfully uploaded.")';
                    echo '</script>';
                }
            ?>
            <hr width="50%">
            </div>
            <div class="content" style="height: 30em; direction: ltr; overflow: auto;">
                <div class="row" style="margin-left:4em;" style="direction: rtl;">
                <?php
                $database = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "videos") or die(mysqli_error());
                $query = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM video");
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $url = $row['url'];
                    echo "<p style='margin:0.5em;'><a href='watch.php?id=$id' style='color:red;'>$name</a></p><br />";
                }
                ?>
                </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**watch.php**

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "videos") or die(mysqli_error());
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM video WHERE id='$id'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $url = $row['url'];
    }
    echo "You are watching ".$name."<br />";
    echo "<embed src='$url' width='400' height='400'></embed>";
}
else
{
    echo "Error!";
}
?>
```

Thank You,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid resending data on refresh in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666882/how-to-avoid-resending-data-on-refresh-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid resubmitting the data upon page refresh. Simply redirect/refresh your page after submitting.

```
echo "alert('Your video has been successfully uploaded.')";
echo "window.location.href=window.location";
```

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion and solution. The ob_start() is not worked for me.

Comment: Welcome. Yes ob_start() is used for something else. Keep on learning...(y)

Comment: BTW you should accept my answer as best answer as it solved your problem instead your own answer

Comment: Sorry,  I just wanted to know about Stack Overflows functionalities. Don't worry I am not that much selfish.   Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

As Per [Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666882/how-to-avoid-resending-data-on-refresh-in-php) itself :

> Please add `ob_start();` in first line of php file itself.

Comment: Do you really think ob_start() will work in this case?

Comment: @Sehdev, Why don't you just give it a try it in your code & let us know whether it worked for you or not ?

Answer (score 0):

```
To avoid resubmission of data/files upon page refresh, we simply need to redirect our page after submission.


Print '<script>alert("Your video has been successfully uploaded.");</script>';
Print '<script>window.location.assign("dashboard.php");</script>';
```

And this worked well for me. Thank you so much for your valuable time you spent on my post and for your beautiful solutions.